# Does 'ipse' truly mean change?

Tags: vocabulary, meaning

This quote hails from the liner notes to [this CD](https://www.earbox.com/john-adams-violin-concerto-leila-josefowicz-david-robertson-st-louis-symphony-orchestra/): John Adams's Violin Concerto performed by Leila Josefowicz, David Robertson of St. Louis Symphony Orchestra. Alice Miller Cotter has a [BA in Music (Berkeley), PhD in Musicology (Princeton)](https://www.linkedin.com/in/alice-miller-cotter-26b5438/).

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ipse#Latin)  and p 1060 on [*Oxford Latin Dictionary* (2012 2 ed)](https://www.amazon.ca/Oxford-Latin-Dictionary-Dictionaries/dp/0199580316) avouch nothing on 'change'.

[image: image of a book mentioning that idem indicates sameness and idem indicates change]

Comment: It's baloney. _Ipse_ means -self

Comment: @AlexB. I agree with Colin Fine - it's baloney.  I read the passage by Ricoeur and I think whatever distinction he's trying to make has nothing to do with Latin _idem_ and _ipse_.  (Frankly, I find it incomprehensible - but then again, I'm not a philosopher.)

Comment: @varro And why should a philosophical concept bearing a certain Latin name have the exact same meaning, as it was used two thousand years ago?

Comment: @AlexB.  All right - you've completely lost me here.  *What* "exact same meaning" are you referring to?  I'm willing to be educated here, but at the moment I'm completely baffled.

Comment: @AlexB. Addendum to my last comment:  are you seriously suggesting that some random person (and yes, for the purposes of *this* discussion, I *do* think that this guy - Ricoeur - *is* some "random person") is someone whose re-interpretation of Latin should be regarded seriously, or for what it is - valueless.

Comment: @varro I imagine it's like how a psychologist's use of _ego_ isn't the same as Cicero's, because Freud co-opted the word for a new concept he was developing. Cotter is referencing Ricoeur, rather than the Classical meaning.

Answer (score 6):

I'm afraid that this question has nothing/little to do with linguistics but rather with **philosophy**. In particular, this question must be understood in the following context where **Ricoeur**'s (famous?) distinction between two kinds of identity in relation to selfhood is summarized: see Section 5. *Narrative Identity and the Turn to Selfhood* in https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ricoeur/
Cf.  "*Idem* identity is the identity of something that is always the same which never changes, *ipse* identity is sameness across and through change".

Answer (score 2):

I cannot see how *ipse* would indicate change.
I would rather say that both *idem* and *ipse* indicate sameness, although in a different way.

There might be an argument for the kind of distinction the text is trying to make, but no such argument is provided in what you quote.
Therefore, until further proof is provided, I see that as a failed analysis of those Latin words.

Answer (score 2):

Let's ignore the quote in your question for the moment.

The question is can a person, writing in a language other than Latin, take a Latin word - or rather, its sound form, perhaps with - or without- some "semantic load", shall we say - and use it in a language other than Latin, and use in a sense that they deem necessary?

The answer is - yes. Examples galore.

Does it have any bearing on Latin? The answer is no.

Now, back to nos moutons (the quote in your question. Unfortunately, Ricoeur’s philosophical distinction is presented there as a fact of Latin lexicology (vocabulary studies). This is certainly not true and imho should be rewritten, with a reference to Ricoeur’s philosophy, not the Latin language.

Comment: I'm not sure how your first "yes" applies to anything except the weakest sense of "can." Of course I *can* use a Latin word for any purpose I deem necessary, but I would certainly feel obligated to introduced at least a tenuous justification for my meaning. So, if your answer reduces to "He can because he did," I don't think it's getting at the heart of the matter.

Comment: @brianpck Whose usus are you discussing, the musicologist’s or Ricoeur’s?

Comment: I don't know enough about either to have an opinion: I was just objecting to one (mis?)interpretation of your answer, which would have it that "I can use Latin words in English for any purpose I want."