# On the interpretation of "ipse" in anticausative constructions

Tags: verbs, pronouns

After having answered a question on "*ipse*" from a very different perspective (a philosophical one: [[Does 'ipse' truly mean change?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/9521/does-ipse-truly-mean-change) ), I return to linguistics: now I was wondering if *ipse* must be considered just a sort of emphatic "reinforcer" of the reflexive in the following **change** construction (Ricoeur again? No, don't worry!):

> *Valvae se **ipsae** aperuerunt* (Cic. *Div.* 1, 74) ‘The doors opened by themselves’.

Would it be possible in Latin to say the following example without *se*? *Ipse* can of course be used in other non-change and non-reflexive contexts (*Ipse dixit*) but I'm not sure if the following example would be well-formed in Latin:

*Foris **ipsa** aperit* ‘The door is opening by itself’.

Cf. the non-emphatic example *Foris se aperit* ‘The door is opening (by itself)’ and the also attested example without *se*: *Foris aperit* (Pl. *Pers*. 300) ‘The door is opening’.

For more context, please read my related question in [How things change in Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/9421/how-things-change-in-latin).

Answer (score 1):

When personal pronouns of the first and second persons are used reflexively, they may be strengthened by a part of "ipse" e.g.

I wounded myself = me (ipsum) vulneravi.

We wounded ourselves = nos (ipsos) vulneravimus

The part of "ipse" is, of course, optional; the personal pronoun is not. Both would be mandatory in e.g.

The king himself had killed himself = rex ipse se interfecerat.

This is not to say that "ipse" cannot stand alone: it can translate as "the very..." as in "femina ipsa" = "the very woman" as an alternative to "the woman herself".

"foris ipsa aperit" = "the very door opens"/ "that-specific-door-opens"; suspect it's ablative in an attempt to achieve "by itself"? Clever; but, don't think so. The strengthening agent (ipsa) needs something to strengthen--the reflexive pronoun.

"ipse dixit"; "ipse" is nominative and a reflexive pronoun cannot be nom., by definition; instead of the accepted "he himself said", it should be: "he, the very man, said".

Comment: From your answer ("The strengthening agent (_ipsa_) needs something to strengthen--the reflexive pronoun"), I understand that the reflexive pronoun _se_ is (expected to be) compulsory in a sentence like _Foris ipsa aperit_. Is that correct? By the way, by using the English translation "by itself" I did not intend to interpret _ipsa_ as ablative (of course, it is not ablative). In any case, thanks for pointing out that 'by itself' is not a good translation of _ipsa_.

Comment: It is perhaps worth pointing out that _foris ipsam se aperit_ is ill-formed unless we provide the door with some agency. A similar contrast is found in Spanish: _La puerta se abrió_ vs. ?? _La puerta se abrió a sí misma_. This said, it seems to me that _Foris aperit_ is **not** identical to Sp. _La puerta abre_. In my Spanish, the latter typically has a sort of generic reading, i.e., it lacks the eventive reading shown in the example above from Plautus (_Foris aperit_ 'The door is opening'). Cf. Sp. ??/*_La puerta está abriendo_ vs. OK _La puerta **se** está abriendo_.

Comment: Mitomino: Yes, reflexive pronoun is compulsory. In your second comment: "...is ill-informed unless we provide the door with some agency." Such as, if the door is opening itself? How would that affect the Latin? Are you writing a book about a haunted house? Sadly, my Spanish is not up to the rest of it.